# problemas em usar o FrameWorks Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estou seguindo uma vídeo aula para entender como se comporta o `vue`, porém essa vídeo aula é em cima de um projeto `PHP`, eu entendo pouco de PHP.
Fiz como forme no vídeo abaixo;

[1 - CRUD en LARAVEL & VUEjs - Webpack, Laravel Mix, NPM, Axios | Rimorsoft Online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EKLN_1mNW8&list=PLhCiuvlix-rSduJ-vKGpPj5xxcmeLabXc)

Porém quando mando subir a aplicação para o servidor digitando o comando **npm run dev** eu não consigo encontrar a URL para visualizar a pagina;

Eu tentei essas opções:

> - localhost/laravel-vue-crud/public/
> - localhost/laravel-vue-crud/
> - localhost:8080

Alguém poderia dá uma olhada no vídeo porque pode ser que eu esteja digitando a URL errada.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que verifiquei, o problema que está ocorrendo é sobre qual URL acessar ao subir o servidor, correto? Se for isto, verifique se você possui o `.env` criado na raiz de sua aplicação.

Basicamente, o `.env` é um arquivo de configuração de todas as variáveis de ambiente do Laravel. Note que se estiver utilizando Linux, todos os arquivos que iniciam com "." são ocultos. Uma outra informação é que este arquivo **não** é versionado, logo ele pode ser copiado do arquivo `.env.example` que geralmente é acompanhado nos repositórios em geral.

Você pode verificar na linha `APP_URL`, ou alterá-la para a porta que deseja, exemplo: `APP_URL=http://localhost:8080/`